# Microsoft 365 Personal subscription renewal - does language version matter at all?

Tags: microsoft-office, localization, subscription

My Personal version of Microsoft (Office) 365 that I have installed in my local language (Slovenian) is up for renewal in a couple of weeks. I usually renew my subscription with a 25-digit code that I receive by buying a subscription in-store which is usually (and strangely) much cheaper than ordering it directly from Microsoft.

However, since the switch from Office 365 to Microsoft 365 local vendors have increased their sale price of the subscription package. Now, I can get an official key for renewal much cheaper if I buy it from abroad, for example from Germany. In this case, however, these versions of Office are localized to that particular market. Now I already have my Office installed and localized - does it really matter where I buy my subscription from? In other words: is buying a key-code country-agnostic when considered from the viewpoint of the renewal process?

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: You can in any language pack with Office 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up: today I've renewed my subscription, using a prepaid code card. It was bought locally, but judging from the information on the sticker, I would say that Microsoft issues cards on a region-wide basis and so those cards should be valid in the whole region for where they were issued.

For example, my sticker, pictured below says: "Eurozone subscr 1YR" and was manufactured in Ireland. This can be interpreted that the card is probably valid for at least those EU countries that use the Euro currency (currently 19).

[image: Microsoft 365 Personal sticker]

Using a key that is meant for a different region and/or trying to renew your locally bought subscription abroad might cause problems, as explained [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_account-mso_other-mso_365hp/office-365-home-billing-countryregion-restrictions/6777dc9d-7fa1-4191-a078-4bf883cf97c4). It might require the user to contact Microsoft support. Possible remedies include opening a new Microsoft account to renew the subscription or (in the case of trying to renew abroad with a locally bought key) the use of VPN that makes it seem that the user is connecting form their home country.

I'll wait a couple of days in case if anyone has anything more to add on this matter, then I will mark the question as solved. Any additional input will be appreciated so it can help other users down the road!

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Office is that the same serial key unlocks all
versions of any language.

There are no serial keys that are language-specific. However, you should ensure
that the downloaded installation file is of the right user-interface language,
so don't download it from the German site.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think as well ... The installation is already localized, it just needs to be renewed, so that shouldn't be too much of a problem ...